# How to stop a while loop specifically python

Tags: python

For python, I need to make my function terminate specifically if the input is a certain input e.g return

Otherwise it needs to keep going... I tried the while True but for some reason it doesnt work.

Comment: Please submit your code and show us which part isn't working as expected

Comment: How is this question unclear? He needs a function with a while True loop that breaks when a condition is met. This is what is killing Stack Overflow. Don't welcome and help the new users. Downvote them and close their questions!

Comment: @jb. - How is it unclear? There's no code, and the question is basically "I need my function to end based on input, and `while True` doesn't work". I'm not even sure whether it's a loop that needs to end the function that contains it, or if it's a function that needs to be called repeatedly. There's basically no question here, and the only possible answers are guesses.

Answer (score 2):

Heres an example, will update when you update with your code but this should give an idea, ideally this wants to be done with a condition instead of being forever:

```
def do_while():
    while True:
        stop = raw_input('Stop?')
        if stop in ('y', 'Y'):
            return 0
do_while()
```

Comment: @BryanOakley He specified the while loop is in a function

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command `break` to break out of the loop:

```
while True:
    ...
    if something > nothing:
        break
```

If you have no other code after your while loop, the function will terminate. You can also call `return` if you truly want to return immediately:

```
while True:
    ...
    if something > nothing:
        return
```

The advantage to the former is that you can have additional code after the loop. For example, you might need to close some files, write a log message, etc.  Also, you can use that version in the global scope (ie: not in a function).

The advantage to the second version is that the function truly does immediately terminate. However, it can only be used inside a function.

Comment: OP specified `I need to make my function terminate`